Incremental algorithm for 2D Linear Programming question for feasible points
I have the following problem that I want to solve using linear programming:
$\max\{-3x+12y\}$ (objective function) and 4 contraints: $-x+2y\leq-1$, $2x-3y \leq 6$, $x-3y \leq 0$, $x+y\leq12$
I start the incremental algorithm by selecting the first 3 constraints to evaluate the starting point. The first three lines intersect at 3 points: $(3,1), (9,4), (6,2)$. The point maximizing the objective function is $(9,4)$. Then I move onto the last constraint which does not include $(9,4)$ so the next maximal point lies on the line $x+y=12$. Solving for $y$ we get $y=12-x$ which can be substituted into the 3 first constraints to solve a 1D LP problem of $-3x\leq 25$, $-5x \leq -42$ and $-4x\leq-36$. These 3 points should then be maximized on the object function $\{-3x\}$, which gives maximum on $x=\frac{25}{3} \approx 8.3333$. However, the points that can I can get are all three right? Including $(9,12)$ which lies on the last constraint line but it clearly is not inside the feasible area. Should that me happening? What if a point is not in the feasible area is selected for maximizing the objective function, although that should not be happening? Is there any assurance that those lying ONLY across the feasible area will be selected?  Or should I also check after every point is computed to see whether it is feasible?
Thanks for any input.

If you want to use linear programming then apply the simplex algorithm. This problem can be solved very good as well by the graphical method.
